# Dealing with multiple forms without unique id:s?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm rendering mulitple forms like this:

```
trait = (name, dice, mod) => {
    return `
    <tr><form action="#" onsubmit="renderRoll()">
        <td><label>${name}</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dice" value="${dice}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mod" value="${mod}"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Slå" name="roll" ></td>
    </form></tr>`;
};

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += trait;
```

The forms don't have unique id:s and there are always more than one in the DOM. How can I run `renderRoll()` and access the values of the form that was triggered?

Comment: By using valid html, either with unique ids or classes

Comment: html is valid without ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an argument inside function "renderRoll()" to work.

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="renderRoll(event)">

function renderRoll(event) {
//here is your target...
var target = event.target;
alert(target.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a unique id as a name for the form element like as below:

```
const trait = (id, name, dice, mod) => {
    return `
    <tr><form name="${id}" action="#" onsubmit="renderRoll">
        <td><label>${name}</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dice" value="${dice}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mod" value="${mod}"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Slå" name="roll" ></td>
    </form></tr>`;
};

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += trait("form", "test", "test", "test");
```

And use form data whenever form has triggered:

```
function renderRoll() {
    let data = document.forms.namedItem("form").elements;
    data = [...data].map(({name, value}) => ({name, value}));

    console.log(data)
}
```

I hope it will be useful.